# What is the name of an experimental design where stimuli are sampled from a large pool and presented to subjects?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, experiment-design

The background of the following question is a research proposal on which I currently advise. I believe the type of experimental design is adequate to the question. However, it turns out hard to communicate it because we do not have a good label for it. So my primary question is whether somebody knows how to label this design.

The goal of the research is to evaluate the impact of features of objects on the perception of the objects by subjects. A feature is, for example, 'color', which may have the levels '{red, green, blue,...}'.

The 'ideal' experimental design would be, I believe, to have a factorial design, in which all relevant features are crossed. However, in this case this is not possible in practice, because building the objects is too expensive. Therefore we have to use objects that are available and have a given combinations of features. We have the possibility, however, to sample from a large pool of objects, which in theory may have all combinations of all possible features.

The ultimate number of features will be moderately large (20 to 30). The idea is to choose a rather large random sample of objects and code all relevant features. Then each subject is randomly shown one (or more) objects. If more than one object is shown, this design has the characteristic of a within-subject experiment. If only one object is shown it is more like a between subject experiment.

In the analysis phase a model predicting 'perception of the objects' from the coded features will be estimated to address relevant research questions on the causal relationship of features and perception.

Questions:

1. Do you think this research design is a good alternative to full
   factorial designs (which are impossible here)?
2. How would you call this design?

**EDIT**:

My statement below made the design quite clear by example: "It would be like a design in which you sample 100 cars and let people rate them (or experience them and measure their experience), then code the features of the cars, and regress experience on features."

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting. However, conjoint would, I believe, still make some sense of systematic combination of the features (and then write these on 'set cards'), whereas we simply plan sample from a pool of objects and present the objects as if they occur in reality. It would be like a design where you sample 100 cars and let people rate them (or experience them and measure their experience), then code the features of the cars, and regress experience on features.

Comment: My comment above was a reaction to a deleted comment that the design would resemble a "conjoint design".

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a variant of conjoint analysis to me. Conjoints are widely used in marketing and other topic areas where a large number of features are tested and combined via a series of experiments in choice-based "trade-offs," potentially to determine an optimal set of features, e.g., as in product design. Here's a Wiki intro to the topic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoint_analysis_(marketing)

Traditional conjoint designs could be quite painful (for hapless consumers) to implement depending on how many features were analyzed. More recent methods have extended them to prediction markets based on concept tests, as in Ely Dahan's paper on *Securities Trading of Concepts*:

http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/ely.dahan/content/chan_dahan_lopoggio.pdf

As well as "conjoint poker," described in this excellent review of the conjoint literature by Oded Netzer:

https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/mygsb/faculty/research/pubfiles/5013/conjoint_poker.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, please see my reply above. I think it is still different enough from the conjoint design. I will look at the links.